# Getting ant to not redirect javac's stderr to stdout

Tags: java, android, ant, gruntjs

I am trying to add an ant-based Android build into a greater grunt-based build system. However, when ant is invoking `javac`, it's redirecting `javac`'s stderr to stdout (when adding the `[javac]` prefix to the console output). Unfortunately, this means that grunt is discarding the useful error output unless I run it in verbose mode - which I'd rather not do.

However, redirecting `ant`'s stdout to stderr causes a different problem, in that the grunt build interprets *any* stderr as an error to abort on.

What I would like for ant to do is to keep `javac`'s stderr output on stderr (so that I see why my build failed), and stdout on stdout. I don't see anything in Android's `build.xml` that would affect this, however, nor has ant's documentation been useful.

And, of course, "simply" porting the ant `build.xml` logic to just be part of the grunt build is a rather large undertaking that I'd rather not do at this time.

So, is there some option to `ant` (or Android's `build.xml`) that I'm missing that is behind the stderr redirection, or is there some other approach to actually getting my error output to display as an error?

Comment: How about using a logger with ant, that will put errors someplace where they are useful to you? You didn't specify exactly what you want to do with the errors.

Comment: I want to see them on the console so that I know why my build failed. I figured that was self-apparent but I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: OK. How important is it that it shows up on the console? If you saved the messages to a file you could look at, isn't that enough?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Saving them to a file isn't ideal but it's certainly better than nothing, and I can always cat it to stderr afterwards.

Comment: Then I suggest you take a look at the various loggers offered by `ant`, or create a custom one.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yeah, that seems like the most straightforward approach. When I get something wired up I'll post it as my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

you just need to use the "-e" option.
you could set the ANT_ARGS environment variable like the following:

```
   export ANT_ARGS=-e
   ant ...
```

or

```
   ant -e ...
```

Comment: Based on trying that just now, that doesn't keep stderr on stderr, it just makes it not adorn the lines when they're sent to stdout.

Comment: My bad, I misread the question that you were asking and gave you the wrong information.  As for an answer to your question. I looked at the ant manual and I must admit that I do not have an answer.  The javac task sends a error message when the javac fails but I was not able to determine why it does not send it to stderr.